# Apply a function to a specific expression for every line in a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I currently am reading the contents of a file to a new file for every case instance where the lines fit a specific criteria. See the code below

```
from string import punctuation

fpath = open('Redshift_twb_1.txt', 'r')
lines = fpath.readlines()

fpath_write = open('Redshift_1_new.txt', 'w+')

# filter the list; with the string 'apple'
# replace 'apple' with whatever string you want to find
temp_out_lines = [line for line in lines if '<column caption' in line]
out_lines = [line for line in temp_out_lines if 'param-domain-type' not in line]

# Lambda function that maps .lower() function to every element of the list out_lines
lower_lines = map(lambda x:x.lower(), out_lines)

# Join the lines into a single string
output = '\n'.join(lower_lines)

# write it
fpath_write.write(output)

fpath.close()
fpath_write.close()
```

My goal is to implement functionality that can read take a line and downcase or lowercase a specific parameter before that line is then written to the new file.

Currently, the process takes in a line, checks if it matches `<column caption`, then checks if it does not contain `param-domain-type`. and if both of those pass, the line is then added to the new txt file.

An example line is below:

```
<column caption='Section' datatype='string' name='[SECTION]' role='dimension' type='nominal'>
```

The goal is to check every line before it is added to the new txt file, and for every instance of `name='[****]'`, make the value within the `[]` lowercase. currently, they are upper case.

Note: only the value within the `[]`'s for the param `name=` can be lowercased. there are other params in the line that must stay capitalized.

Thanks!

Edit: Another option would be to do a make shift **find and replace** that would find all instances with `name='[ABC]'`, and replace it with `name='[abc]'`. But still, I do not know how to go about this on my own.

Edit2: Upon implementing Regex, I have also used a for loop to loop through every instance of the txt file... see below code.

```
for x in range(len(out_lines)):
    print(out_lines[x])
    test = str(out_lines[x])
    out_lines[x] = re.sub(r"(name='([.*?])')", lambda m: m.group(1).lower(), test)
    print(out_lines[x])
```

However when I do so I still get the same output:

```
<column caption='Location' datatype='string' name='[MANAGEMENT_LOCATION]' role='dimension' type='nominal' />

<column caption='Location' datatype='string' name='[MANAGEMENT_LOCATION]' role='dimension' type='nominal' />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use re python module to replace necessary substring.

```
import re
re.sub(r"(name='(\[.*?\])')", lambda m: m.group(1).lower(), <YOUR TEXT>)
```

Comment: If i was to use regular expression for this, then how could i maintain the value of the text, but just lowercase it? what does the <YOUR TEXT> arg do? @Nick Po

Comment: <YOUR TEXT> is text where you need to replace substring. 
`your_text = "<column caption='Section' datatype='string' name='[SECTION]' role='dimension' type='nominal'>"
re.sub(r"(name='([.*?])')", lambda m: m.group(1).lower(), your_text)`

the output would be <column caption='Section' datatype='string' name='[section]' role='dimension' type='nominal'>

you can capitalize using re.sub(r"(name='([.*?])')", lambda m: m.group(1).capitalize(), your_text)
@Chandler Cree

Comment: Thanks for helping out, please see bottom of question for follow up @Nick Po

Comment: sorry in my comment I used wrong regex. 
to capture in correct way you need to use 
`out_lines[x] = re.sub(r"(name='(\[.*?\])')", lambda m: m.group(1).lower(), test)`
also you can check you regex pattern in some web tools like https://regex101.com/
@ChandlerCree

Comment: also if you need capability to upper you value of parameter better to use this form
`re.sub(r"(name)='\[(.*?)\]'", lambda m: f"{m.group(1)}='[{m.group(2).lower()}]'", test)`
In this way we have to captured group: 1 captures name of parameter and 2 captures value and then we use mask {parametr}='[{value}]' to format. In this way you can do lower and upper transformation of the value. @Chandler Cree